# Force Unity to register only interfaces when using RegisterTypes

Tags: c#, unity-container

I want to register specific **interfaces** of my assemblies and map them to **concrete** types, using the ***RegisterTypes*** method.

They get registered well, but as a result I also get the concrete types being registered as From types.

For example, instead of having just ITenantStore interface mapped to TenantStore class, I get not only that mapping but also TenantStore mapped to TenantStore.

How can I register only the interfaces as From types? Or is there a efficient way to delete the registrations going from one class to the same class?

**Edit**: here is a sample code

```
var myClasses = AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath().Where(t => t.Namespace.StartsWith("MyProject", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

container.RegisterTypes(myClasses, 
                  WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, 
                  WithName.Default, 
                  WithLifetime.ContainerControlled, 
                  getInjectionMembers: t => new InjectionMember[]
                  {
                     new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
                     new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>()
                  });
```

Comment: Can you provide the registration and resolving codes? If your registrations is the similar as `container.RegisterType<IFoo, MyClass>();` so `container.Registrations` will have two regitrations: `IUnityContaner` and `IFoo to MyClass`. It doesn't contain registration `MyClass to MyClass`.If I don't understand something in your question please explain it.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria I am talking about the `RegisterTypes` method, not the RegisterType one. I don' want to use RegisterType because I would have to register all classes by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Your container have registrations from `ImplementationType` to `ImplementationType` because you pass arguments `getLifetimeManager` and `getInjectionMembers` into `container.RegisterTypes`. So `container.RegisterTypes` checks 
this params and if the condition bellow is correct it registers current type the second time without type mapping. It registers current type for the first time with type mapping during invocation of `UnityContainerRegistrationByConventionExtensions.RegisterTypeMappings`:

```cs
    string name = getName(type);
    var lifetimeManager = getLifetimeManager(type);
    var members = getInjectionMembers(type).ToList();

    // UnityContainerRegistrationByConventionExtensions.RegisterTypeMappings(container, ...) – It's invocation of common registration 
    // for current type to getFromTypes(type). getFromTypes is WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface in your case

    if (lifetimeManager != null || members.Count > 0)
        container.RegisterType(type, name, lifetimeManager, members);
```

At this moment I can suggest don't pass this two arguments to `container.RegisterTypes` and you would not have a duplicate registrations...

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @GeorgeAlexandria the reason why "duplicate" concrete registrations appear is because the code is written that way.  The behavior is by design.

One reason it's done this way is to avoid registration by convention changing the core logic and to account for some edge cases in supporting different scenarios. For example, in Unity the `InjectionMembers` and `LifetimeManger` are associated with the concrete type.  If the concrete type is not explicitly registered this can cause unexpected behavior when re-registering types with different lifetime managers and/or injection members.

Internally, when you call

```
RegisterType<ITenantStore, TenantStore>(new 
    ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionMember[]
    {
        new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
        new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>()
    });
```

a mapping is registered, the `LifetimeManager` is associated with the concrete type `TenantStore` via a policy and and the injection members policies are added associated with the concrete type `TenantStore`.  Basically, a mapping is created for the interface to the concrete type and policies are added indicating how to customize the build plan for the concrete type.  Although the exact code path is slightly different I think it is very similar to what happens with the registration by convention approach with the one apparent difference being the concrete registration appearing in the public Registrations property.

If the behavior is causing an issue or is just irritating you could always register the classes yourself.  If the situation is straight forward it could look like this:

```
var myClasses = AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath().Where(t => t.Namespace.StartsWith("MyProject", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
foreach (var type in myClasses)
{
    var matchingInterfaceName = "I" + type.Name;
    var interfaceType = type.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => string.Compare(i.Name, matchingInterfaceName, StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0);

    if (interfaceType != null)
    {
        container.RegisterType(interfaceType, type, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionMember[]
            {
                new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
                new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>()
            });
    }
}
```

This isn't much more code the the convention approach but is pretty naive and does not support generics properly.