# Is there an easy way to register lots of classes in Unity container in a similar way?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I have about 40 Interfaces like the following examples:

```
IDaProduct
IDaStudent
IDaUniversity
…
```

And 40 repository classes that implement these interfaces:

```
RepProduct
RepStudent
RepUniversity
…
```

And 40 provider classes that implement these interfaces too:

```
PrvdProduct
PrvdStudent
PrvdUniversity
…
```

I register these types in the container in the following way using Unity library:

```
container.RegisterType<IDaProduct, RepProduct>("Repository");
container.RegisterType<IDaProduct, PrvdProduct>("Provider");


container.RegisterType<IDaStudent, RepStudent>("Repository");
container.RegisterType<IDaStudent, PrvdStudent>("Provider");


container.RegisterType<IDaUniversity, RepUniversity>("Repository");
container.RegisterType<IDaUniversity, PrvdUniversity>("Provider");
```

I want to know if there is any easier and automatic way for registering all of these 80 classes?

I need something like this:

```
container.RegisterType<"All interfaces started by IDa", "All Classes started by Rep">("Repository");
container.RegisterType<"All interfaces started by IDa", "All Classes started by Prvd">("Provider");
```

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431500/how-can-i-dynamically-register-generic-classes-with-a-name-with-unity

Comment: I think that you are looking for `UnityContainerRegistrationByConventionExtensions.RegisterTypes`. You can find on SO a more examples of usages. For examples, [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534794/force-unity-to-register-only-interfaces-when-using-registertypes) of them and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31438468/5359302)

Answer (score 2):

Unity can register types by convention (also known as auto-registration)

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterTypes(
  AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
  WithMappings.MatchingInterface,
  WithName.Default);
```

see [Dependency Injection with Unity](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/D/B/4DBC771D-9E24-4211-ADC5-65812115E52D/DependencyInjectionWithUnity.pdf)